# how to pass vuex data in computed property to data prop

Tags: vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

I need a help to send sending data from vuex, and in computed: {} to data prop(data() {return {}})

I've tried watch: but my case doesn't work since it has to be send as props after that.

Btw, I can't get the store value in anywhere except computed property in any vue component which makes me upset...... I'm digging this issue for four hours now.. please help.

```
<template>
     <pie-chart :data="chartdata" />
</template>

 data() {
    return {
chartdata: [] //<<<<- I need to set the data from vuex here but calling this.$store.getters.myGetter() doesn't work
    }
},

  computed: {
    aa() {
      return this.$store.getters.getCurrentTodPlanARing;
    },
  },
```

I don't see any problem in my vuex. I get all the data correctly in computed only!!!.
Somehow for some reason, I have only initial data which is an empty array in vuex whenever I call it in mounted, methods, or even data property(data() return {}}.

So I have to pass my vuex data to data prop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your vuex data directly you could just create a computed property and use it. YOu donn't need that extra step to store it in a data property.

```
<template>
     <pie-chart :data="chartdata" />
</template>

  computed: {
    chartdata() {
      return this.$store.getters.chartData;
    },
  },
```

So everytime the vuex store gets updated, the chartData property will get updated aswell.

If you need to modify your vuex data, before passing it to the PieChart, you could either create a watch on that computed property or simply create another computed property which, will do the work for you.

```
<template>
     <pie-chart :data="modifiedChartData" />
</template>
computed: {
    chartdata() {
      return this.$store.getters.chartData;
    },
    modifiedChartData(){
      const data = this.chartdata;
      //Do your modifications here
       return data;
    }
  },
```

with watch:

```
<template>
     <pie-chart :data="modifiedChartData" />
</template>
data(){
  return {
    modifiedChartData:[]
  }
}
computed: {
    chartdata() {
      return this.$store.getters.chartData;
    },
  },
watch:{
   chartdata:{
      handler (value){
        //do modifications here
        this.modifiedChartData = value;
     },
    immediate:true
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man I do need to modify it so I'm trying to bind it to data prop. I will try it on Monday and update the comment. I'm running out of time. I'm guessing it might work but not sure cause watch didn't work before. It didn't send the modified data at all. Anyway, I will update! Have a great weekend! :)

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much! It worked out so well :) Though watch doesn't send the updated data right after when the component initialized, so I've added v-if="isLoaded". :) Have a great day!

Comment: To avoid this v-if logic, you can use the long-hand version of the watcher and add  immediate:true. This will trigger the watcher instantly on the component's creation. I updated my answer for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to copy data from Vuex/getter into `data` ? Just use `computed` as you did with `aa`

From the wording I assume your Vuex store is initially empty and data are loaded with some async Ajax call (fetch/Axios)

`data` is a function which is called by Vue when the component is created. If you use Vuex getter like this:

```js
data() {
    return {
      chartdata: this.$store.getters.getter
    }
},
```

`chartdata` will be initialized with current getter value (presumably empty because Ajax call is still in progress) and **it will not get updated** when the data arrive

Comment: this doesn't work.... that's why I'm trying to copy it... it gets only initial data...

Comment: yah, thats what i said...dont try to copy getter data into `data`

Comment: Yeah I got you right, but as I said on the question up there, I need to send it down to a data prop by binding all the relative data... <pie-chart> is a chart wrapper component. Is there a way that I can bind to data prop? or should I fix the structure?